# How to find all transactions regarding a NFT token?

Tags: etherscan, nft, opensea

I'm trying to link Opensea with Etherscan and find all transaction details for a token. However, I found that some sales/transactions listed on Opensea were not reflected on Etherscan. Can anybody help me understand what is going on here?

One example is the following:
For this token: [Contract addr 0xD9c036e9EEF725E5AcA4a22239A23feb47c3f05d, token ID 1264](https://opensea.io/assets/0xd9c036e9eef725e5aca4a22239a23feb47c3f05d/1264)
On this page we can see that the first sale's price is 1ETH, the tx hash is 0x2a80565bb83b5f3b45b18a70bdeca8a8c8aaaa548c298bfe3985b1169de9affa. However, if I go to Etherscan for historical transactions of this contract here:[txs history of Contract addr 0xD9c036e9EEF725E5AcA4a22239A23feb47c3f05d](https://etherscan.io/address/0xd9c036e9eef725e5aca4a22239a23feb47c3f05d), we cannot find such a sale. Instead, we can see a lot of transctions with the price of 0Eth. What do they mean and why the first sale data is missing on Etherscan?

Another related question is on the opensea page above, we can see the first sale, then 3 transfers. My understanding is one sale follows with one transfer. Does that mean the other two transfers are sales that happened on other platforms such as looksrare and not on opensea? So that Opensea does not know the sale price?

Thank you very much for helping me understand the details.

Comment: That's strange. If you have the contract address you should see it on etherscan unless it was created on a different chain. The 0 eth might be some tom-foolery that opensea is doing when folks create a NFT on their site. I've noticed that you pay no gas for this - which doesn't make sense to me. Maybe they're rolling up many creations into one tx once someone actually transfers it / sells or something. I'm curious to find out the answer though. I"ll follow this thread.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. Actually, I found a lot of such examples from opensea. So I wonder whether I missed anything here. This is not an exceptional case.

Comment: yeah. that's a strange thing. i'm following this thread so hopefully we'll get some answers! good luck.

Answer (score 1):

NFT sales often consist of two parts:

1. **The actual sale** - this transaction has method type "Atomic Match_".
2. **the transfer to the final owner** - this transaction has method type "Transfer From"

I assume this is because sales involve intermediaries, e.g. a DEX.

Looking at your specific case, the transaction history (https://etherscan.io/token/0xd9c036e9eef725e5aca4a22239a23feb47c3f05d?a=1264) does show a transaction of type "Atomic Match_" for 1 ETH, which is transaction https://etherscan.io/tx/0x2a80565bb83b5f3b45b18a70bdeca8a8c8aaaa548c298bfe3985b1169de9affa.

Plus, there's a later transaction of type "Atomic Match_", which is also a sale (https://etherscan.io/tx/0xa52e82afea2efd1349315699dccd0e78cdb17ec141a5763f2937e2c6a2b0a955). Because the currency used here is WETH, not ETH, the ETH value is 0. Still, you can see the WETH transferred in the field "Tokens Transferred".

All the other transactions are not sales.

Comment: This is very helpful Umer! Thanks a lot. It seems that I should go to the contract address on etherscan and add "?a=tokenid" to the URL to see the transactions of a particular NFT. Is that right? Also, what does “Transfer From” mean? Is it from the marketplace to the owner?  I clicked at download to csv at the end of the page using the first link you posted and got an empty file everytime. Do you happen to know why? Again thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, adding "?a=tokenid" to the URL only shows you that particular NFT.

Comment: There are 2 types of transfers: 1) “Transfer" with which you as the owner can move the NFT and 2) "Approve" & "TransferFrom” which let's you approve someone else who then is permitted to move the NFT on your behalf. E.g. if you want them to pay the gas fee.

I can imagine that the buyer has to pay the gas fee. Therefore the seller (current owner) approves the buyer, so that the buyer can the move the NFT and pay the corresponding gas fee.

Comment: By the way if I'm helpful to you, could you upvote & accept the answer/comments :)

Comment: I actually did that immediatly, but my reputation is not enough yet so my vote didn't show up here...